# Get ting the index of the non zero connections in scipy csr graph

Tags: python, scipy, python-3.6

Say I have a scipy csr graph. When I call the print routine on the graph object it returns the index and the value.

```
G_dense = np.array([[0, 2, 1],
                     [2, 0, 0],
                     [1, 0, 0]])
G_masked = np.ma.masked_values(G_dense, 0)
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
G_sparse = csr_matrix(G_dense)
print(G_sparse)

#  Return
#  (0, 1)   2
#  (0, 2)   1
#  (1, 0)   2
#  (2, 0)   1
```

If I use `print(G_sparse.data)` it shows the `[2 1 2 1]`(only the weights).
I wanted to know, if I can retrieve the indices
i.e `(0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (2,0)`
using some function.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: First, you don't need the `np.ma` step.  `G.indices` and `G.indptr` is where `G` stores its indices.  But the `coo` format is probably what you want to see.  Try `G.nonzero()` to see those as a tuple of arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj I just grabbed the example from the scipy documentation just for the reference. ```G.nonzero``` does return the required indices. Thank you!